# Python perform actions only at certain locations in text file

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have a text file which contains the data like this

```
AA 331             
line1 ...   
line2 ...    
% information here     
AA 332   
line1 ...    
line2 ...    
line3 ...   
%information here    
AA 1021   
line1 ...   
line2 ...  
% information here      
AA 1022    
line1 ...   
% information here     
AA 1023    
line1 ...    
line2 ...    
% information here
```

I want to perform action only for "informations" that comes after smallest integer that is after line `"AA 331"`and line `"AA 1021"` and not after lines `"AA 332"` , `"AA 1022"` and `"AA 1023"` .

P.s This is just a sample data of large file

The below code i try to parse the text file and get the integers which are after "AA" in a list "list1" and in second function i group them to get minimal value in "list2". This will return integers like [331,1021,...]. So i thought of extracting lines which comes after "AA 331" and perform action but i d'nt know how to proceed.

```
from itertools import groupby
def getlineindex(textfile):
    with open(textfile) as infile:
    list1 = []
    for line in infile :
        if line.startswith("AA"):
            intid = line[3:]
            list1.append(intid)
    return list1

def minimalinteger(list1):
     list2 = []
     for k,v in groupby(list1,key=lambda x: x//10):
           minimalint = min(v)
           list2.append(minimalint)
     return list2
```

list2 contains the smallest integers which comes after "AA" [331,1021,..]

Comment: I think your question could use some clarification. What's the 'smallest integer' after the lines you specified? Where in the line does it occur, and is that position consistent/reliable? Furthermore, how did you come up with 'AA 331' and 'AA 1021' as indicators of data you wish to process? Is this something that you're expecting to receive as input from a human, or is there a way to computationally determine it?

Comment: smallest integer i mean 331 < 332 and 1021<1022<1023 . so i want to perform action at "% information " line which comes after AA 331 block that is before line AA 332.

Comment: You'll notice, of course, that 331 < 332 < 1021 < 1022 < 1023. So why should we process 1021?

Comment: ok got it. they are blocks of  integers of 10. so they are randomly generated  but with interval of 10. so 332 is kind of duplicate of 331 and 1022 -1024 are duplicates of 1021 so i want to retain blocks 331 and 1021. [blocks i mean from line AA 331 until % information here which is before line AA 332]

Comment: I think you should scan the whole file at first to get all integers which are smallest (as you described) and then scan file again and process required blocks only.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want to find the minimum of any group of 10 to process. But even this is vague. Do groups of ten start at the actual minimum value (e.g., we should process 331, then ignore 332-340)? Or, are groups of tens lumped based on the digits, ignoring the ones place? (e.g., 331, 333, 334, 339 are from one run since they're in the 334th group of ten, and 340, 343, 345 is for the next, the 335th group of ten?)

Comment: Who are preparing a file for you? May be it will be easer and better to change file format? For example, is it possible to print to file only important information or print some markers for your program?

Comment: Yes !! and groups of ten will not start at actual minimal value, but once they are generated they always increment by one . (e.g 524,525,526) next group (1237,1238,1239) and next (1240,1241,1242). from this interested ones are 524,1237 and 1240 .

Comment: @Jimilian files are computationally generated :-)

Comment: @Danira, I have updated my solution. I think it should works.

Comment: @Danira, And what about if there's a random gap in the middle of a set of 10? So, if you have 300,301,302,305,306,307 should we process 300 and 305? (sorry I'm grinding against edge cases here, but I think it's necessary to get you the help you need)

Comment: @bmhkim Great question !! i dint think of that. yes, in that case we process 300 and 305 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's my solution. At a high level, I go line by line, watching for AA lines to know when I've found the start/end of a data block, and watch what I call the run number to know whether or not we should process the next block. Then, I have a subroutine that handles any given block, basically reading off all relevant lines and processing them if needed. That subroutine is what watches for the *next* AA line in order to know when it's done.

```
import re

runIdRegex = re.compile(r'AA (\d+)')

def processFile(fileHandle):
    lastNumber = None  # Last run number, necessary so we know if there's been a gap or if we're in a new block of ten.
    line = fileHandle.next()
    while line is not None:  # None is being used as a special value indicating we've hit the end of the file.
        processData = False
        match = runIdRegex.match(line)
        if match:
            runNumber = int(match.group(1))
            if lastNumber == None:
                # Startup/first iteration
                processData = True
            elif runNumber - lastNumber == 1:
                # Continuation, see if the tenths are the same.
                lastNumberTens = lastNumber / 10
                runNumberTens = runNumber / 10
                if lastNumberTens != runNumberTens:
                    processData = True
            else:
                processData = True

            # Always remember where we were.
            lastNumber = runNumber

            # And grab and process data.
            line = dataBlock(fileHandle, process=processData)
        else:
            try:
                line = fileHandle.next()
            except StopIteration:
                line = None

def dataBlock(fileHandle, process=False):
    runData = []
    try:
        line = fileHandle.next()
        match = runIdRegex.match(line)
        while not match:
            runData.append(line)
            line = fileHandle.next()
            match = runIdRegex.match(line)
    except StopIteration:
        # Hit end of file
        line = None

    if process:
        # Data processing call here
        # processData(runData)
        pass

    # Return line so we don't lose it!
    return line
```

Some notes for you. First, I'm in agreement with Jimilian that you should use a regular expression to match AA lines.

Second, the logic we talked about with regard to when we should process data is in processFile. Specifically these lines:

```
        processData = False
        match = runIdRegex.match(line)
        if match:
            runNumber = int(match.group(1))
            if lastNumber == None:
                # Startup/first iteration
                processData = True
            elif runNumber - lastNumber == 1:
                # Continuation, see if the tenths are the same.
                lastNumberTens = lastNumber / 10
                runNumberTens = runNumber / 10
                if lastNumberTens != runNumberTens:
                    processData = True
            else:
                processData = True
```

I assume we don't want to process data, then identify when we do. Logically speaking, you can do the inverse of this and assume you want to process data, then identify when you don't. Next, we need to store the *last* run's value in order to know whether or not we need to process this run's data. (and watch out for that first run edge case) We know we want to process data when the sequence is broken (the difference between two runs is greater than 1), which is handled by the else statement. We also know that we want to process data when the sequence increments the digit in the tens place, which is handled by my integer divide by 10.

Third, watch out for that return data from dataBlock. If you don't do that, you're going to lose the AA line that caused dataBlock to stop iterating, and processFile needs that line in order to know whether the next data block should be processed.

Last, I've opted to use fileHandle.next() and exception handling to identify when I get to the end of the file. But don't think this is the only way. :)

Let me know in comments if you have any questions.

Comment: Perfect Explanation for my problem. Great solution . I will work with my sample data and let you know. Anyway this is what i wanted so accepting. Thanks a lot for your time :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like:

```
import re

matcher = re.compile("AA ([\d]+)")
already_was = []
good_block = False

with open(filename) as f:
   for line in f:
        m = matcher.match(line)
        if m:
           v = int(m.groups(0)) / 10
        else:
           v = None

        if m and v not in already_was:
            good_block = True
            already_was.append(m)
        if m and v in already_was:
            good_block = False
        if not m and good_block:
            do_action()
```

These code works only if first value in group is minimal one.

Comment: Yes i edited my question after your answer . Thanks a lot for the help :-)